# How to change jupyter notebook port when running tensorflow docker?

Tags: docker, tensorflow, jupyter

I'm having hard time understanding the differecne between transaction and span

For instance, if you run docker using the following image

```
tensorflow/tensorflow:${VERSION}-gpu-jupyter
```

How do you change the port jupyter server is running?

Answer (score 0):

```
docker run --gpus all -v /home/local_user:/tf/notebooks -p 8889:8888 -it --rm tensorflow/tensorflow:2.3.2-gpu-jupyter
```

You can now start jupyter on localhost:8889 or change 8889 to any desired port for the host.

Port mapping ref:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports

Answer (score 0):

You may also need to disable to update the Dockerfile "HEALTHCHECK"
or you will finds the container dying after around 46 seconds of run time!

https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/issues/1817